# linux: can't create a link

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, ln

I faced to next trouble when I try create a link

```
sudo ln /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread_nonshared.a /usr/lib64/libpthread_nonshared.a
```

I get: '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread_nonshared.a' not such file or directory. Despite *locate* return exactly same result:

```
locate libpthread_nonshared.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread_nonshared.a
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The *destination* likely doesn't exist. Either create /usr/lib64 then link. Another option is to just symbolically link the entire directory.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib64
```

Ubuntu uses the path x86_64-linux-gnu, while many other distros use the lib64 path. I'm guessing you are installing/using something that is only looking for /usr/lib64/*